# Add website field using event observer in magento admin role permissions

Tags: magento

I'm creating a module that allows the user to choose the website during creating a role permission (System -> Permission -> Role -> Add New role -> Role Resource). I'm using an observer to achieve this, however I cannot get the form object.

**Observer.php**

```
class Mymodule_Mycompany_Model_Observer 
{ 
    public function appendCustomRow(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if (!isset($block)) {
            return $this;
        }
        if ($block->getType() == 'adminhtml/permissions_editroles') {       
            //get form instance
            $form = $observer->getEvent()->getForm();
            //create new custom fieldset 'website'
            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('website', array(
                'legend' => 'Website Extras',
                'class' => 'fieldset-wide'
                )
            );
            //add new field
            $fieldset->addField('website', 'text', array(
                'name'      => 'website',
                'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Website'),
                'title'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Website'),
                'disabled'  => false,
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

**Mymodule/Mycompany/etc/config.xml**

```
<adminhtml>
         <events>
            <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                <observers>
                    <Event_column_append>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>Mymodule_Mycompany_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>appendCustomColumn</method>
                    </Event_column_append>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
          </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I worked it out. Here is the modified piece of code that works

```
public function appendCustomColumn(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
    if (!isset($block)) {
        return $this;
    }
    if ($block->getType() == 'adminhtml/permissions_tab_roleinfo') {       
        //get form instance
        $form = $block->getForm();
        //create new custom fieldset 'website'
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'website_field', 
            array(
                'legend' => 'Website Extras',
                'class' => 'fieldset-wide'
            )
        );
        //add new field
        $fieldset->addField('website', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'website',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Website'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Website'),
            'disabled'  => false,
        ));
    }
}
```

XML Configuration:

```
<events>
    <adminhtml_block_html_before>
        <observers>
            <Event_column_append>
                <type>model</type>
                <class>Mymodule_Mycompany_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>appendCustomColumn</method>
            </Event_column_append>
        </observers>
    </adminhtml_block_html_before>
</events>
```

1. You need to use the event 'adminhtml_block_html_before' as the event which you were  using did not even create the form object. That is why you were nt able to access the form object.
2. The block that is creating this form elements was 'adminhtml/permissions_tab_roleinfo'.
3. The method you were using was the not same one in the observer.

Hope that helps :)...

Cheers,
Swapna

Comment: Awesome. This is what I exactly need. Thank you so much friend :)I thought im having problem in event name. And one more thing now currently its showing in Role info tab. I want website field in Role Resource tab. How do I do that?

Comment: Will it auto save the values? or do we need to set it via _saveBefore Events?